# How to fill in the value of input with chosen date from calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a datepicker. I have a function that creates a calendar, I need to fill in the value of my input with the date from the calendar.

```js
function createCalendar(year, month) {
  var inputDate = $("#calendar-input");
  var calendar = $("#calendar")
  var mon = month - 1;
  var d = new Date(year, mon);
  var table = "<table><tr><th>пн</th><th>вт</th><th>ср</th><th>чт</th><th>пт</th><th>сб</th><th>вс</th></tr><tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < getDay(d); i++) {
    table += "<td><a href=\"#\"></a></td>";
  }
  while (d.getMonth() == mon) {
    table += '<td><a href=\"#\">' + d.getDate() + '</a></td>';
    if (getDay(d) % 7 == 6) {
      table += "</tr><tr>";
    }
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  }
  if (getDay(d) != 0) {
    for (var i = getDay(d); i < 7; i++) {
      table += "<td><a href=\"#\"></a></td>";
    }
  }
  table += "</tr></table>";
  calendar.html(table);
}

function getDay(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();
  if (day == 0) day = 7;
  return day - 1;
}
createCalendar(2018, 12)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with this code?

Comment: do you need to fill the $("#calendar-input") with a date a user clicked on in the calendar?

Comment: no, this code only creates table but doesn't fill my input

Comment: yes, I need to fill the $("#calendar-input") with a date a user clicked on in the calendar

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you could create an `onClick` event for each date field. This `onClick` event would call a function, using the date as an argument. It would then be up to this function to fill the input field with the chosen date.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem as it is stated you can use this event listener:

```
$('#calendar a').click(function() {
  $( "#calendar-input" ).val( $( this ).text() );
});
```

I assumed that you are using *jQuery* as you have $ with selectors in your code, so I used it too, though it's not necessary here.

I can't use your variable `inputDate` as it belongs to the `createCalendar` function, so I just inlined the selector `$( "#calendar-input" )`. However, you always can refactor that by moving the declaration of that variable or in some other way.
As soon as you don't have any class in your `<a>` tags and on the other hand the only `<a>` you have in your code are the tags for dates I used a too general `$('#calendar a')` selector but that is wrong. I strongly recommend you to put some class or another attribute to the `<a>` tags and to narrow this selector.